# PL/SQL data types conversion

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqldatatypes

I am writing a PL/SQL procedure and I'm having a problem with type conversion. Here is my code:

```
create or replace FUNCTION fn_easy7 (att in nfl5.att%type, 
    comp in nfl5.comp%type, td in nfl5.td%type,inter in nfl5.inter%type, 
    yds_g in nfl5.yds_g%type, yds in nfl5.yds%type)
RETURN number IS
   a number;
   b number;
   c number;
   d number;
   e number;
BEGIN
   a :=  (((comp/att)*100)-30)/20;
   b := ((td/att)*100)/5;
   c := (9.5 - ((inter/att)*100))/4;
   d := ((TO_NUMBER(yds, '999')/att) - 3)/4 ;
   e := (a + b + c + d)/ 0.06;

   RETURN e;
END fn_easy7;

update nfl5
   set rate = fn_easy7(att , comp, td ,inter, yds_g, yds);
```

Description for table `nfl5:`

```
 Name      Null   Type         
---------- -----  ------------ 
  COMP            NUMBER(4)     
  YDS             VARCHAR2(8)  
  TD              NUMBER(3)    
  RATE            NUMBER       
  YDS_G           VARCHAR2(5)
```

Type of rate number as well. I have error numeric or value errors.

Comment: First thing to check is the non-numeric columns in your table YDS and YDS_G. What values are in the table? Can they all be converted to a number?

TO_NUMBER(yds, '999')

(never mind yds_g, it is in your parameter list but never used).

Comment: O, and the specifications of columns att and inter are missing. What types are they?

Comment: please post full description of table nfl5. for sure this in your post is not complete as it misses inter, att colums.